# Is it possible to configure IntelliJ to not index specific files?

Tags: intellij-idea

Scripts and styles for the project I'm working on get compiled and minified into single (enormous) files when the project is built. When IntelliJ goes to index everything, it spends a significant amount of time indexing the minified files, which are all but useless for the purpose of searching.

Is there a way to ignore specifically these files, and not just a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking mostly a guess here, IntelliJ docs are notorious for being not-so-helpful on some topics.

Try [marking the files as plain text](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/excluding-files-from-project.html?search=exclud):

> When a file is marked as plain text, IntelliJ IDEA does not use it anymore for code completion and navigation...The reverse action is also available: you can return a file to its original type, using the Mark as  action

---

Edit: After hearing that your files are dynamically created, I think I may have figured out a solution.

IntelliJ allows for the creation of [Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/scope.html?search=inspection#configure), which allow you to exclude certain files from the project. You can then go to `Editor -> Inspections` and change the scope of each inspection from `All Scopes` to your new scope

Comment: The files get re-created every time the project is built, so that marking disappears unfortunately. It would probably need some sort of rule- or pattern-based marking.

Comment: @MattDs17 I looked around the docs, and may have found something that'll help you

Comment: I made a scope which captured the two files properly, but I'm not sure how to configure the inspections correctly - ended up causing a lot of errors with the linter.

Comment: @MattDs17 When in Inspections, set `All Scopes` to the name of your scope, and uncheck it's box. That'll disable inspections on those files